# Program for specific sequence of Integers

Tags: matlab, wolfram-mathematica

I am solving steady state heat equation with the boundary condition varying like this 10,0,0,10,0,0,10,0,0,10,0,0,10.... and so on depending upon number of points i select.
I want to construct  a matrix for these boundary conditions but unable to specify the logic for the sequence in terms of ith element for a matrix.

i am using mathematica for this however i need the formula only like for odd we can specify 2n+1 and for even 2n , something like this for the sequence 10,0,0,10,0,0,10,0,0,10,....

Comment: why did you tag matlab if it is for mathematica?

Comment: i can do it in both but i was preferring mathematica, thats why i tagged matlab

Comment: what you have is a vector of numbers, not a matrix. What is the dimension of the required matrix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you specifically want a mathematical formula let me suggest a method:

```
seq = PadRight[{}, 30, {10, 0, 0}];

func = FindSequenceFunction[seq]
```

> ```
> 10/3 (1 + Cos[2/3 \[Pi] (-1 + #1)] + Cos[4/3 \[Pi] (-1 + #1)]) &
> ```

Test it:

```
Array[func, 10]
```

> ```
> {10, 0, 0, 10, 0, 0, 10, 0, 0, 10}
> ```

There are surely simpler *programs* to generate this sequence, such as:

```
Array[10 Boole[1 == Mod[#, 3]] &, 10]
```

> ```
> {10, 0, 0, 10, 0, 0, 10, 0, 0, 10}
> ```

Comment: Wizard Thanks alot for the nice answer. Sorry for late i didn't looked back to this question till now.

Comment: @FarrukhShehzad You're welcome, and thank you for letting me know that you appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

In MATLAB, it would be

```
M = zeros(1000, 1);
M(1:3:1000) = 10;
```

to make a 1000 long vector with such structure. `1:3:1000` is `1,4,7,...`.

Comment: thanks alot it worked ... i will follow up with something like this in mathematica now .. once again bundle of thanks .. stay blessed ..

Comment: @FarrukhShehzad: Please accept the answer if you were satisfied with it. This marks the question as answered and may thus benefit the community.

Answer (score 0):

A way to do this in Mathematica:

```
Take[Flatten[ConstantArray[{10, 0, 0}, Ceiling[1000/3] ], 1],1000]
```

Another way

```
Table[Boole[Mod[i,3]==1]*10, {i,1,1000}]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer . i am sorry i did not looked again to this question as i was able to do it. Thanks again :)